# Google Map Autocomplete: how to know when suggestion is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete. Is there a way to know when a user selects an item in the suggestion list? Any events triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't a "place_changed" event will be fired?

I based on the [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), **"[Getting Place Information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#getting_place_information)"** section.

Source code of the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete) can see there is a

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    ...
});
```